# Does the good/evil avatar have a basis from any concept?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

I'm trying to find the picture and from what episode but in the *Legend Of Korra* I believe Jinora was in the airbending temple and she comes across another Avatar.

It displays an Avatar with black and white spirits going back and forth.

I guess my question becomes what basis does this have?  Is it implying the Avatar must sometimes be good/evil?  Alternatively is it based off of a specific religion?  Maybe this is better suited for the mythology site not really sure.  I am pretty sure she says "What Avatar is this?" but I can't find the it from [searching the transcripts available](https://web.archive.org/web/20190817045504/http://korra.avatarspirit.net/transcripts.php).

The scene looks similar to this.

[image: Someone stands with their back to the viewer, looking up at a tall figure floating in the air; the figure wears black robes outlined in gold light. Looping around the figure are black bands, also outlined in gold, which connect to a black-and-gold symbol floating above the figure's head.]

Comment: I am voting to close because the question is extremely opaque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, but it has nothing to do with the statue.**

Your picture is from episode 2 of Book 2 ("The Southern Lights"), some 19 minutes into the episode. It starts with Jinora being called to the statue of one of the Avatars (whom we later learn is Avatar Wan) in her sleep and sleepwalks there. When we see Jinora before we see the statue it's either just before dawn or the scene's made a bit brighter for the viewers' convenience:

[image: Jinora sleepwalking in the statue room.]

Going by the shape of the windows and the positioning of the statues I suspect that this is on one of the balconies of the statue room: earlier on in the episode (around the 11 minute mark) we see an establishing shot of the Southern Air Temple panning upwards alongside its great tower, which has windows that roughly match the windows we see here:

[image: The great tower of the Southern Air Temple.]

When we see the statue of the First Avatar its lower half is dimly lit while the upper half is cloaked in shadow, which builds an air of mystery around who this might be:

[image: He was number Wan.]

This was foreshadowed earlier in the episode (12 minutes in) where Jinora detects something subconsciously but doesn't know what it is. In turn, this foreshadows Jinora's strong spiritual connection that is developed later in Book 2. The statue does not have hands, likely because it's an old wooden statue and they have broken off sometime since its creation.

When Korra opens up the Southern Spirit Portal the statue starts to glow, much like how the eyes of all the statues started to glow back in Book 1 Episode 3 of *The Last Airbender* ("The Southern Air Temple"). However, it's not the entire statue that starts to glow: it merely looks like it's glowing with an inner light much like how the Avatar hosts the Spirit of Light, Raava. We only see the statue of the First Avatar glowing like this, which might be because he was the one to close the portal in the first place. It also means that the title of the episode might have a double meaning: the lights that appear when Korra opens the portal and the fact that a statue in the Southern Air Temple starts glows when she does so.

Winding this all back to your earlier question: the Avatar does have both light and dark inside of them. The Avatar is the human host of the Spirit of Light, Raava. She has a counterpart to whom she's eternally bound: Vaatu, the Spirit of Dark. Raava states that as long as she exists so will Vaatu. The opposite is true as well: in the finale of Book 2 we see Korra reach into the Dark Avatar and pull out Raava, who had been pulled out of her and was seemingly destroyed by Unalaq in the previous episode. Since one cannot destroy one another, Vaatu must still exist since Raava still exists. And since Raava existed in Vaatu, Vaatu must exist inside Raava. And since Raava exists inside the Avatar, so does Vaatu.

It stands to note that Raava and Vaatu symbolise Yin and Yang, contrasting and balancing each other. When we first see the two spirits they are in conflict with one another, physically entangled as they struggle. The Avatar meanwhile exists as an agent of balance, which is in line with what Yin and Yang symbolise together rather than one of them. In fact, the word "Avatar" comes from the Sanskrit avatāraḥ, which means the manifestation of a deity on the world, which is kind of what the Avatar is. The various avatars of the deity Vishnu are an important part of Hinduism, with the difference being that Vishnu has innumerable incarnations compared to the Avatar's unique condition.

**So yes, there is a real-life version of the concept of the Avatar because its very name is derived from said concept. However, it has nothing to do with the statue you see in that episode.**

Comment: Thank you for the analysis.  I find it interesting that she has no hands.  Still curious if this has any connection to Hinduism or not.

Comment: @William Good questions, I've updated the answer with those questions (first paragraph after the third image, second-to-last paragraph in the answer).

Comment: Hmm I find the old wooden statue part a little hand wavy.  Wouldn't they all be built of the same material?

Comment: @William The thing is that not all statues are made at the same time. Aang's statue is the most recent because he's Korra's predecessor, therefore is statue is less old than that of Roku's statue, who is Aang's predecessor. A counteragument to this however would be that the looks and placements of the statues is inconsistent between TLA and LoK, which either insinuates that all the statues are remade whenever an Avatar dies or that the animators changed things up for some reason.

Comment: Hmm I assumed it was Korra and therefore was more recent.  Unless this dates back to the last convergence.  Maybe it is Vaatu?